# Dependency Injection in a distributable Javascript library?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, dependency-injection

We are using Backbone to create reusable components. We create controllers in order to setup bindings between models and views. We wish to offer people the ability to replace the models and views with their own implementations.

Since the majority of people will use the the components we provide, I don't want to force developers to configure or create anything that isn't different from the defaults.

This means that someone should be able to pass an instance of an object they want to use as a model or view to the controller, all configured and setup and ready to go, or they can pass in some configuration to what the controller will use by default.

I am not sure what the best approach is.

```
// Idea #1
var controller = new Controller({
    dependencyA: {
         conf: { // config for depedencyA }
    },
    dependencyB: {
         conf: { // config for dependencyB }
         class: custom.implement.Class
    }
});
```

In this approach, the user doesn't have control over how to instantiate the object. What's bad about this is, for example, Backbone models take two arguments in the constructor while views only take one.

```
// Idea #2
var controller = new Controller({
    dependencyA: {
        args: ['arg1',{
            opt1: 'opt-value',
        }]
    },
    dependencyB: {
        args: ['a','b','c']
        class: custom.implement.Class
    }
});
```

Args would be the arguments passed to a constructor. This means the controller calls the constructor with the args array, and again this only really benefits you if you're passing in custom configuration for default dependencies. If you want to pass your own implementation it's more awkward.

```
// Idea #3  
var controller = new Controller({
    dependencyA: new outOfBoxModel({ // configuration }),
    dependencyB: new custom.imeplement.Class('a','b','c')
});
```

In this approach, the user is forced to instantiate the out of box model. If the model's default settings are all appropriate though, then the user is doing unnecessary work. The only bit they HAVE to do is create an instance of their own custom implementation.

I am not sure what the best approach would be here?

Comment: In your application, are users required to construct instances of `Controller`, or is that something your application could construct, and return to the user in another way?

Comment: users would have to construct it. Most likely, they would be adding this to their own application.

Comment: Use #3, it is the most flexible, and the controller must not know how to instantiate the dependencies. If you end up with some boiler plate code for the default cases, offer a wrapper utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the three approaches, I most prefer approach number 3. Here is why:

1. *It is more consistent than the other approaches*. In the 3rd approach, the user only has to learn to pass in constructed instances of dependencies into the controller. In the other approaches, the user has to pass in either args, or args and a class name.
2. *It does not violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)*. In the first two approaches, your controller is made responsible for constructing and configuring its dependencies. This doesn't feel like dependency injection at all! I think it's better, and simpler, to leave the construction of dependencies to the user or another part of your application. In my opinion, its not a terrible thing to force the user to construct their own implementations - it gives them the freedom to define their constructors however they want, rather than forcing you to define and maintain constructor APIs for the `Controllers` dependencies, and forcing the user to conform to them.

A different idea:

If you have this freedom in your application, I would consider putting your `Controller` construction logic in a factory class or method:

```
var createController = function(config) {
  // Parse, validate, extract relevant config items
  // var a = create dependency a
  // var b = create dependency b
  return new Controller(a, b);
}
```

This approach allows you to be as fancy as you want with your definition of `config` - you could support all three of the config definitions you provided in your original post - although I wouldn't recommend that :-). At a minimum, I would have the factory method support a zero args invocation (in which case it would return the default construction of `Controller`) and one of your preferred config definitions.